# url returns XML on browser, but doesn't when using cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm sending few parameters, via post to an url using CURL, the url is supposed to return the results in a XML, but instead it returns a string with the result.

If I copy the url and my variables and paste it in the browser, it returns the desired XML.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $variables);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r($result);
```

That's the piece of code that I'm using. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question so we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Speculation: You are getting XML, but you are outputting it from PHP with the default `text/html` content-type and looking at it rendered in a browser which is treating all XML tags as unknown HTML tags and rendering them in a similar way to spans.

Answer (score 0):

Take the string that cURL returns and turn it into an XML object

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

SimpleXML documentation [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add http headers:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml", 
]);
```